# Curl command to PHP script

Tags: php, curl

So I need to create a Curl Script in my PHP and I am confused I don't know that much Curl (As in I only know how to copy and paste and cross my fingers).

The Curl Command is

```
curl https://website.com/v1/route -u key-of-power
```

so far I have

```
                $ch = curl_init();
                curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, https://website.com/v1/route);
                curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1 );
                curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
                curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
                $payment_response = curl_exec ($ch);
                curl_close ($ch);
```

so I need to know where `key-of-power` goes so my curl can pass.

Thank in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERNAME, "$username")` will do it. More detail is [here](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_USERNAME.html).

Comment: YOU ARE AWESOME thanks, Hate how people blindly down vote -_-